# Agregar un array a serialize en Javascript y utilizarlo en controlador Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, json

Soy nuevo con Javascript y Laravel pero estoy teniendo un problema que ojala puedan ayudarme.

En mi view estoy enviando los datos de un formulario utilizando serialize. Esto funciona perfectamente, lo recibe mi controlador y lo almacena la base de datos.

El problema es que tambien quiero enviar una informacion recolectada de una celdas en un array (la cantidad de filas puede variar). Lo hago con este codigo y estoy adjuntando todo a los datos (uso JSON.stringify antes)

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#ajaxsubmit').click(function(e){
    $('#contenido').hide();
    $('#loading-screen').show();
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    let datospagos=[]; //creo array

    $("tr.filapago").each(function() {
        tipopago = $(this).find("td.idtipopago").html();
        formapago = $(this).find("td.formapago").html();
        montopagado = $(this).find("td.montopagado").html();

        datospagos.push({

            tipopago,
            formapago,
            montopagado,

        });
    });

    datospagos = JSON.stringify(datospagos);

    var datosformulario = $('#formcomplete').serialize(); //captura el formulaario
    var data = datosformulario + '&datospagos=' + datospagos; //agrega a data el contenido de lo capturado en el array
    
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('facturacion.store') }}",
        method: 'post',
        data: data,

        success: function(result){
            $('#loading-screen').hide();
            if(result.errors)
            {
                $('#contenido').show();
                jQuery('.alert-danger').html('');

                jQuery.each(result.errors, function(key, value){
                    jQuery('.alert-danger').show();
                    jQuery('.alert-danger').append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
                });
            }
            else
            {
                jQuery('.alert-danger').hide();
                location.reload(); //refresca la pagina
            }
        }});
});
});
```

Al revisar estoy enviando todos los campos del formulario y creo que envio bien el array dentro de datospagos (sale al ultimo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como hago luego para cargar los valores del array en mi controlador?
Cuando pido con mi codigo me responde como null. Probe con esto:

```
$datospagos = $request->input('datospagos');

    foreach((array) $datospagos as $datospago) {
        $recibo = new Recibo();
        $recibo->idformapago = $datospago->tipopago;
        $recibo->monto = $datospago->montopagado

        $recibo->save();
    }
```

Pero no funciona.

¿Podrian guiarme? Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué te arroja cuando obtienes $request->all() ? veo que conviertes con JSON.stringify, tal vez necesitas hacer un json_decode($params, true) para que puedas tener el array, sin embargo primero revisa qué esta llegando en el request.

Comment: Con lo poco que entiendo creo que el problema esta en:

 var data = datosformulario + '&datospagos=' + datospagos;

$request->all() No me esta devolviendo la segunda parte (justamente lo de datospagos). Si envia todo el resto (datosformulario)

Comment: Se me ocurrio convertir usando este codigo

datospagos = JSON.stringify(datospagos);
datosformulario = JSON.stringify(jQuery('#formcomplete').serialize()); // store json string
data =  datosformulario.concat(datospagos);

Pero sigue sin pasar la segunda parte (datospagos)

Comment: Sí, parece que lo que falta es convertir el json a cadena pero también a caracteres válidos de html ya que las comillas por ejemplo deben ir en código html, cuando les das serialize en jquery ya la función lo hace, entonces se me ocurre que puedes asignar el valor que te devuelve JSON.stringify a un campo hidden "name=datospagos" dentro del formulario y al hacer serialize ya debe ir ahora sí con información.